# What does “Rückkoppelung” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, noun

I received an e-mail ending with

> Gib mir bitte eine Rückkoppelung zu diesem Thema.

Does it mean *Antwort* here?

I looked it up in a dictionary and it did not help

Comment: _Rückkoppelung_ means feedback (normally only in the technical sense). It's used tongue-in-cheek here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works. Note that for questions asking for a meaning, we typically require you to perform prior research, i.e. look up the word in a dictionary. Did you do so and did it help you or not? Please [edit] the question to include those details.

Comment: The _technical sense_ others talked about is this: If you have an amplifier (from your Stereo) with speakers and a microphone attached and then place the mic in front of the speakers and pump up the volume – _**that's**_ a _Rückkoppelung_. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say so, yes! To be precise it means feedback, so the whole sentence reads as follows:

> Please give me your feedback about this topic.

To have a blind guess: I think, he wanted to write *Rückmeldung* instead of *Rückkoppelung* (which has the same meaning in physics/mechanics), but the latter one is not used as a synonym for feedback. Maybe he used a translation service which translates without context.

Comment: I don’t think a machine translation is the culprit. I think it’s the person’s humour.

Comment: You're right! It's probably humourous.Even if leo.org *Rückkopplung* as the [first match for the phrase](https://pda.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=feedback) *feedback* returns. :D

Answer (score 3):

The first and last time I heard the word *Rückkoppelung* in the real world was in university in an electrical engineering class. There it meant *(electrical) feedback to a specific input*. Thus, I dare say your assumption, *Rückkoppelung* equals *Antwort, Rückmeldung, Feedback,* is right.

Even if the sentence itself sounds noticeably strange to me as a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

> Gib mir bitte eine Rückkoppelung zu diesem Thema.

Shouldn't be used in a classical email threat in terms of asking for feedback. Since it is used to describe the tune in your speaker when you hear yourself. Basically it is the tune you send via your mic and get broadcast via speaker on the other end and captured via the mic on that side to bring over to you again. Now you hear yourself in your speaker. That is a "Rückkopplung".

Your email should: "Gib mir bitte ein Feedback zu diesem Thema."

Comment: Your answer does not add substantially to PerlDucks comment, and I consider the proposed *Feedback* (already covered in several answers, too) as inferior compared to *Rückmeldung* already suggested, so *should* may be a bit strong.

Comment: How does asking go together with a threat?